# Can JDBC connection strings specify multiple databases?

Tags: jdbc

Here's my current connection string:

```
jdbc:amazon;moduleName=Foobar:oracle:thin:@ab1na-orasvr.db.foobar.com:42111:ab1na
```

But I need JDBC to access multiple databases.  Can I simply append the second module name, separated by a semi-colon?

Comment: Sorry, this is a really basic yes/no question.  Just want to be sure before I go chasing my tail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I don't think you can do this. You can do this with Hibernate though by creating multiple persistence units and creating entity managers based on the name you give each unit.

http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/JPA+Tutorial+1+-+Persistence+Unit

Answer (score 3):

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=2)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=3)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=4)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=5)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=6)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=7)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=8)(PORT=1521))(FAILOVER=on) (LOAD_BALANCE=ON)) 
(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER=DEDICATED) 
(SERVICE_NAME =ccbfsinterface.comp.pge.com)))
```